# How to improve performance in image loading on web application?

Tags: performance, image

I have a web application running on local host. The requirement is to load multiple rectangular jpg images (96 images, average 7k in size each) and show on home page when it runs. Images are showed in a grid of 8x12 rows/columns. I am loading image by setting the 'src' attribute of the 'img' in javascript. The url assigned to the 'src' attribute is same for all images but the image id is different. Images are loading but the main issue is that they are not loading very quickly and they are some what loading in a sequence means 1,2,3,4... and so on but some images are not loaded in sequence. I want to improve the performance of this page. I have tried the figure out the timings at different points like:

1. When call is originated form client (image src attribute is set)
2. When server is receiving call. (the page on server which serve individual image)
3. When server is about to return the image.
4. When on client side image is received/showed  (image loaded event called in javascript)

It turned out after looking at the collected data that main time is lost between 1 and 2 above that is between the client side call is originated and server is receiving call for a particular image.

I have also tried setting parameters like maxWorkerThreads, minWorkerThreads, requestQueueLimit and maxconnection in machine.config but no significant improvement yet.

Can someone please help me in this situation as i am stuck here since many days and i am really short of time now. Desperately needs to improve the performance of these images loads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the grid never needs the full size images, have you considered putting many images in one large image file and use a CSS sprite approach?

Comment: Hi Jonas, Yes that's one idea which is in mind yet. But the problem is that those images are run time images received remotely form another application. If i need to implement something like CSS sprite then i need to combine all those images into one big image at run time right after client access that page everytime. Do you think there is some approach to do that?

Comment: Nope, if the images are unpredictable, you're probably lost. Have you evaluated whether the remote application serving the images may be the bottleneck? In that case, caching could be an approach (see E-Tag and Last-Modified).

Comment: No there is no bottle neck on remote application side. Actually they are available all the time but can be updated any time with a newer version. So at any time the images are there in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since you stress the lack of time, I would advise you to try a jQuery plugin that loads images on demand. The gallery in which you load the pictures, does the user scroll in it? Or is it 1 big field?
If it's a gallery the user can scroll in, I'd strongly suggest you take a look at [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). What this plugin does, is it fetches the image only when it is needed. As long as it's not on the screen, it will not be loaded. For a brief example, have a look at [this demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html).

I hope this can help you out.

Comment: Actually there is no use of lazy loading or image on demand because as soon as page URL is hit it needs to load all the images at the same time and there is no scroll as images are small enough to fit in a page. You can say it is similar to seeing images at google images without any scroll. i am not sure how google images are loaded too fast. Need help?

Comment: In that case, making an (even smaller) thumbnail could help you out.. Although since your initial images are already only 7KB in size, that wouldn't reduce the load time much.

Comment: Any other thing i can do to load images faster on the web page?